# React-router and iframe, browser history

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, react-router, browser-history

I came to the kind of anyoing problem. So, I have a component in `react` and also using `react-router`. Everything works almost great. This component has a list of items, when you click on one, it pushes url to the `iframe[src={url}]`. And here appears the problem, if I will click on several items and then click on the previous page/back button, instead of going to the previous page, it just shows the previous iframe of url that was pushed to iframe.

What do I do in this situation?

@I'm using `react-router-dom v4`

Comment: do the buttons change the url of the main window page?

Comment: You mean, when I push the url to iframe? No, url stays the same.

Answer (score 14):

Don't just change the src. You've to replace a new iframe everytime the src change.
By doing that without change things much, just add difference key to your iframe everytime you change src

```
render() {
  const iframe = <iframe key={this.thing.id} src={this.thing.src} />;
  return iframe;
}
```

Comment: bad english but yes. iFrame was messing with my router history - until I set a unique key to the iframe for each new time I display it. Would love it if someone gave an explanation as to why this works.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to [@Expl0de](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1834000/expl0de) answer,

You should add a unique value to the `key` attribute, which will change from `src` to `src`, each time the iframe is reused.

The issue happens because an iframe changing the `src` attribute is considered as content navigation, being pushed to the `window.history` browser stack.
When you go back in the browser navigation it just loads the same page, same iframe with a different `src` attribute.

When adding a `key` prop that changes on different `src` values, React will unmount and remount this iframe element, because it is not the "same element" anymore. This will prevent the iframe from changing the browser's history.

A more in-depth explanation, covering React's Reconciliation Process and examples, can be found here: https://www.aleksandrhovhannisyan.com/blog/react-iframes-back-navigation-bug/